# Spawn new consoles from script and get back to the main console instance

Tags: bash-scripting

The goal is to use a script to launch and execute a command in n separate window terminal: (I use lxterminal)

It works when I copy/pase the following block of commands, It executes each lines sequentially and open all 3 terminals.

```
echo "terminal 1"
lxterminal -e  "htop" 
sleep 2
echo "Next action"

echo "terminal 2"
lxterminal -e  "htop"
sleep 2
echo "Next action"

echo "terminal 3"
lxterminal -e  "htop"
sleep 2
echo "Next action"
```

But as soon as I use a script, for each iteration, it open the new window and wait there.
And I have to close the spawned console for the main script to execute the next instruction:

**$ sudo ./loop.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1; i<=3; i=i+1 ))
    do
        echo "terminal $i"
        lxterminal -e  "htop" #==> at each iteration the script stops here and pass the control to the new terminal
        sleep 2
        echo "Next action"
    done
```

Is there something else to do for the script to execute entirely and stay in the main console?

Comment: Any explanations on why the question is downgraded?

Comment: People vote for all sorts of reasons.  However, I observe that the behaviour that you describe is not the behaviour that exhibits when one follows the steps that you have provided.  As is all too often the case, **you've omitted stating a very important part of exactly what you are doing**.  Ironically, it's that part that leads to the explanation of what's going on.  Describe what you are doing exactly, and completely; with sufficient exactitude that people can reproduce what you claim happens, and thence explain to you what and why.

Comment: You are right JdeBP, I omitted to mention that I was using "sudo" to execute the script, without it, it works as expected.